# Load huge JSON data in browser

Tags: json, database, performance, memory-management

From an API I load 15000 json objects and thats around 100mb.

Please suggest whats the best way to handle that data. I have very good machine (12GB and i7) an my Chrome never crash with that data but I suppose that my clients sometimes use a older machine with just 4GB o RAM.

Is it a problem for older browser to handle 100mb of json.
It a designer app and sometimes all 15000 object properties  needs to be updated real time. Of course I do not show all all 15 000 in DOM - I split into chunk of arrays.

Please suggest whats the best wya to handle a large amount of JSON data. Is it backend - MongoDB or some in-memory database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IndexDB? ......

Comment: Updating a large JSON document in real time in a web browser seems like a terrible idea. JSON is not really made with performance in mind since it is a text-based file format and parsing/serializing texts is generally particularly slow. Executing sequential web-based stuff (JS?) in the double sand-box of Chrome does not help either... Try any in-memory binary file format first (one with performance in mind at least). For the computing part, try web-assembly if needed.

Comment: I split json in array of collections then pages and products and update using jquery .each ...